# Why is Expess Js showing request body undefined even after using body parser?

Tags: json, express, undefined, content-type, body-parser

I'm having issue with the request body being undefined even after using the body-parser. I'm using prefixed routing also.

```
 //adding router
const route = require('./routes/route')
app.use('/api',route)


//body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

This is the issue.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at E:\Projects\MEAN\routes\route.js:24:29
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (E:\Projects\MEAN\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
```

Comment: Even when self-answering, the **question** has to be complete, including any necessary code to replicate the problem and a full description of the problem. That is, you need to post a question that could have been answered even if you didn't post an answer. If you do that, it's absolutely fine and encouraged to post an answer to your own question. But the **question** must be complete and answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused when I used router config above the body-parser config

like this

```
//adding router
const route = require('./routes/route')
app.use('/api',route)


//body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

but simply changing the order solved my issue.
like this,

```
//body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//adding router
const route = require('./routes/route')
app.use('/api',route)
```